API is not hitting while browser refresh in Angular
I've one project where API has been written in .net framework using C# and frontend is in angular.

In the Angular I've used one API into OnInit method.
Code is running fine when i'm using Visual Studio for API and VS Code for angular to run it.
Post Uploading the build of both on IIS, the angular is not hitting the API that is in "OnInit" method when I'm refreshing the browser, however when I put the same API inside any action button (click) then the same API is showing correct (updated) value.
Tried in Constructor as well but same result after deploying into IIS.
Once I uploaded on IIS and run the code it is showing the details and later If I make changes in the backend and refresh the page then it should show me the updated details but still showing the the old detail. I thought some cache issue but don't know for sure.
Connection/permissions on IIS is correct, I've provided ADMIN access to App Pool and sites.
I tried passing the no-cache as well in the API through angular but still hard luck.

    ngOnInit(): void {
     this.service.myAPI(this.currentValue).subscribe(updatedVal => {
        this.Display = updatedVal;
        this.dataSource.data = this.serviceDisplay;
      });
    }

When I use the same API in some another method that is envoked by clicking on a button then it is giving me updated value. example code is below.
 

ActionMethod(val:any){
this.service.myActionAPI(val).subscribe(e=>{console.log(e)}
 this.service.myAPI(this.currentValue).subscribe(updatedVal => {
    this.Display = updatedVal;
    this.dataSource.data = this.serviceDisplay;
  });
);
}

Please help me out and comment if you need more info

Have you tried adding cache-control headers to your service?

Yes, I did tried that.
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Pragma': 'no-cache'
})
};
passed the same in the API in onInit and put as an optional in the service , because it is taking only 1 parameter.

could you try disable caching in iis; image add headers like this :    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
'Pragma': 'no-cache'. try to access the site in private mode and test

just a note: "I've provided ADMIN access to App Pool"  ...sounds a bit dangerous.  You should give it only the access it absolutely needs... limited to only directories needed and specific DB if needed.  As is, if an exploit is found the attacker now has ADMIN access to your server.   Even a bug in server-side code might cause more damage if privileges aren't limited.

I think your Angular application has SSR enabled, then what happens is, the server runs the ngOnInit once and caches the data, so that there is no need to make the same API call again, when rehydrating on the browser. But when you click some buttons and make the API call, the data might change, so it triggers the API call again.
If you do not like this, you can use withNoHttpTransferCache, to disable this cache.
But it's better to embrace it, since it makes your application more performant.

Disabling SSR will work?. How to use withNoHttpTransferCache in this api? Any suggestions.

@ADeveloper If you are using SSR, then you will have provideClientHydration, in either app.config.ts or main.server.ts, here just add provideClientHydration(withNoHttpTransferCache())

It worked. My bad I didn't opened afterwards. thank you so much @Naren Murali for the help. Really Appreciate it.
